# Excel Autofilter when no criteria is met

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel VBA I want the count to be displayed as zero when filter criteria is not met and otherwise I want it to display the exact number of filtered rows. However the counter displays 1 when no results satisfy criteria and even when 1 result satisfies criteria.

```
On Error Resume Next
If .Range("D3", Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp)).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "" Then
MsgBox "vs4 is zero"
V_S4 = 0
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("E5").Value = V_S4
Else
V_S4 = .Range("D3", Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).count
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("E5").Value = V_S4
End If
```

Comment: you may want to give more details about your data to be filtered structure

Comment: Isn't it because your header is still visible? When you filter data and have a header, the header is visible. Your range is most likely containing the header as well?

Comment: How'd it go? Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim lrow, i As Integer

lrow = Cells(rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1

i = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("D1:D" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) - 1

If i=0 then
MsgBox "vs4 is zero"
V_S4 = 0
Else
```

I believe this should work, let me know the result please, I'm keen to give it another go if needed.